# How to bind mouse button to an action in console in CS

Tags: counter-strike

I wanted to bind mouse buttons like MWWHEELDOWN to a command (for Mod servers). How can I do this ? 
`bind MWWHEELDOWN +power1` doesnt work !

Comment: You have an extra W. It's just mWheeldown, not mWWheeldown

Comment: Yeah just noticed that yesterday :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind mouse buttons by opening the console with ~, and entering:

bind mwheelup "*action*"

Some examples would be:

bind mwheelup "+jump"

or

bind "mouse3" "use weapon_hegrenade"

And here a guide to general key binding in CS!

http://www.counter-strike-source-tips.com/counter-strike-source-binding.html

Comment: my bad i was binding with two `W` s :D